# Why am I getting an error of list not being defined?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nameerror

I keep getting an error:

> NameError: name 'animal_list' is not defined for line 4

I have gone through my code and can't seem to figure out why.  Thanks for any help!

```
import Animal
def main():
    animals = make_list()
    print("Here is the data you entered:", display_list(animal_list))

def make_list():
    animal_list = []

    run = True
    while(run):
        atype = input("What type of animal would you like to create? ")
        aname = input("What is the animals name? ")

        alist = Animal.Animal(atype, aname)

        animal_list.append(alist)

        another = input("Would you like to add more animals (y/n)? ")
        if (another !="y"):
            run = False

    return animal_list

def display_list(animal_list):
    print("Animal List")
    print("------------")
    print()
    for item in animal_list:
        print(item.get_name(), "the", item.get_animal_type(), "is")
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the `animals` but `animal_list`, change to this, should work:

```
def main():
    animals = make_list()
    print("Here is the data you entered:", display_list(animals))
```

As the `animal_list` is within `make_list` function scope, and you have no access to this name within `main()` function scope.

As you're returning `animal_list` from `make_list` and assign `animals` to the result, you should just pass this to `display_list` directly.

Comment: @helpplease, lol no worries it happens to everyone occasionally. Just in case, I also explain why you couldn't access the names in another function